# manipulate list in python

Tags: python, list-manipulation

I'm doing a python challenge and I cannot go further...
I need to verify if the numbers in the vetor are primes.
Like:

- vetor = [2,5,12]

  - 2 is prime(TRUE)
  - 5 is prime(TRUE)
  - 12 not prime(FALSE)

This is my code until now:

```
vetor = [ ]

def is_prime():
    x = vetor
    if x == 1:
        return False
    elif x == 2:
        return True


    for i in range(x):
        if (x % i) != 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False




def number():
    value = int(input('Write an integer number bigger than 1: '))
    if value >= 1:
        vetor.append(value)
        return number()
    elif value < 0:
        return number()
    elif value == 0:
        return is_prime()

print(number())
```

But doing this, Python returns me:
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

What could I do to manipulate that data inside my list?

Comment: you've defined `vetor = [ ]` which is a `list` datatype, and `x = vetor`, which conflicts when you compare the `list` to an `integer` datatype in `if x == 1:` and `elif x == 2:`. You'll want to iterate over each element in the `x` list and do the comparison test, i.e. `for i in x: if i == 1:`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to evaluate the value of a 'whole' list (datatype) against an integer (datatype) value (1 or 2), and then you're using the whole list as it were a single integer value again. You should address every single value in the list and check it separately.

You can do it, per example, with a for-each loop:

```
for value in vetor:
    #do wahtever you want with 'value'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
vetor = [ ]

def is_prime(x):
    if x == 1:
        return False
    elif x == 2:
        return True


    for i in range(1, x):
        if (x % i) != 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False




def number():
    value = int(input('Write an integer number bigger than 1: '))
    if value >= 1:
        vetor.append(value)
        return number()
    elif value < 0:
        return number()
    elif value == 0:
        for x in vetor:
            if is_prime(x):
                print(x, 'is prime')
            else:
                print(x, 'is not prime')

print(number())
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend making `is_prime` accept an integer as an argument. Then it's just a pure function that takes in an integer and outputs a boolean value.

I also notice a problem in your is_prime implementation. In your `if`-`else` statement, the function returns no matter what during that statement, so the for loop will always stop after only one iteration. You should only return False if *all* of the divisors you check do note divide the number:

```py
import math

def is_prime(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return False
    for d in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n))+1):
        if n % d == 0:
            return False
    return True

# >>> is_prime(7)
# True
# >>> is_prime(8)
# False
```

I also think it would be clearer to write your program iteratively, rather than recursively (your number function currently calls itself). This might look like

```py
vector = []
while True:
    value = int(input('Write an integer bigger than 1: '))
    if value == 0:
        break
    elif value > 0:
        vector.append(value)
for n in vector:
    print(n, is_prime(n))

# prints something like:
#
# 1 False
# 2 True
# 11 True
```